# cannot parse headers to create MIME message

Tags: java, apache, api, email, jakarta-mail

I'm trying to send messages only to myself, not out to or through the intertubes, based on the [Apache NNTP API](http://commons.apache.org/net/).  The particular class involved takes an [NNTP message](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nntp) and attempts to parse it into a regular MIME type message as so:

```
package net.bounceme.dur.nntp;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.mail.Address;
import javax.mail.Header;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.NoSuchProviderException;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

public class MessageSender {

    private final static Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(MessageSender.class.getName());
    private String header;
    private String body;
    private Properties p;
    private Session session;
    private MimeMessage message;

    private MessageSender() {
    }

    public MessageSender(Properties p, String... s) throws Exception {
        header = s[0];
        body = s[1];
        this.p = p;
        populate();
    }

    private void populate() throws Exception {
        String lines[] = header.split("\\n");
        session = Session.getDefaultInstance(p, null);
        message = new MimeMessage(session);
        LOG.fine("\n\n\n\nnew message************\n\n\n\n");

        for (String s : lines) {
            if (!s.contains("comp.lang.java.help")) {
                message.addHeaderLine(s);
            }
        }
        message.setContent(message, body);
        String recipient = p.getProperty("recipient");
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                InternetAddress.parse(recipient));
        try {
            send();
        } catch (javax.mail.internet.ParseException e) {
            LOG.warning(e.toString());
        } catch (com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPAddressFailedException e) {
            LOG.warning(e.toString());
            List<Address> addresses = Arrays.asList(message.getAllRecipients());
            for (Address a : addresses) {
                LOG.info(a.toString());
            }
        }
    }

    private void send() throws Exception {
        String protocol = p.getProperty("protocol");
        String host = p.getProperty("host");
        int port = Integer.valueOf(p.getProperty("port"));
        String username = p.getProperty("username");
        String password = p.getProperty("password");
        Transport transport = session.getTransport(protocol);
        LOG.log(Level.FINE, "{0}{1}{2}{3}{4}", new Object[]{protocol, host, port, username, password});
        Enumeration enumOfHeaders = message.getAllHeaders();
        while (enumOfHeaders.hasMoreElements()) {
            Header h = (Header) enumOfHeaders.nextElement();
            LOG.log(Level.FINE, "\n\n\nHEADER\n{0}\n{1}", new Object[]{h.getName(), h.getValue()});
        }
        transport.connect(host, port, username, password);
        transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
    }
}
```

But I'm having trouble with the headers:

```
init:
Deleting: /home/thufir/NetBeansProjects/apache_nntp/build/built-jar.properties
deps-jar:
Updating property file: /home/thufir/NetBeansProjects/apache_nntp/build/built-jar.properties
Compiling 1 source file to /home/thufir/NetBeansProjects/apache_nntp/build/classes
compile:
run:
200 Leafnode NNTP Daemon, version 1.11.8 running at localhost (my fqdn: dur.bounceme.net)
GROUP comp.lang.java.help
211 35 3 37 comp.lang.java.help group selected
HEAD 3
221 3 <7e60dce5-09d7-4cee-bbc1-137207f03dd0@googlegroups.com> article retrieved - head follows
BODY 3
222 3 <7e60dce5-09d7-4cee-bbc1-137207f03dd0@googlegroups.com> article retrieved - body follows
Feb 24, 2013 3:05:04 AM net.bounceme.dur.nntp.MessageSender populate
WARNING: javax.mail.internet.ParseException: Expected '/', got wrote
HEAD 4
221 4 <kfpdt3$5g9$1@dont-email.me> article retrieved - head follows
BODY 4
222 4 <kfpdt3$5g9$1@dont-email.me> article retrieved - body follows
Exception in thread "main" javax.mail.SendFailedException: Invalid Addresses;
  nested exception is:
    com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPAddressFailedException: 450 4.1.8 <markspace@nospam.nospam>: Sender address rejected: Domain not found

    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.rcptTo(SMTPTransport.java:1863)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:1119)
    at net.bounceme.dur.nntp.MessageSender.send(MessageSender.java:80)
    at net.bounceme.dur.nntp.MessageSender.populate(MessageSender.java:54)
    at net.bounceme.dur.nntp.MessageSender.<init>(MessageSender.java:35)
    at net.bounceme.dur.nntp.ArticleReader.<init>(ArticleReader.java:28)
    at net.bounceme.dur.nntp.Driver.<init>(Driver.java:13)
    at net.bounceme.dur.nntp.Driver.main(Driver.java:17)
Caused by: com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPAddressFailedException: 450 4.1.8 <markspace@nospam.nospam>: Sender address rejected: Domain not found

    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.rcptTo(SMTPTransport.java:1730)
    ... 7 more
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 6 seconds)
```

Now, I appreciate that there's no domain for the sender.  Nonetheless, I want to go ahead and send the message.  Do I need to change the sender?  I'd like to muck with the headers as little as possible.

If there's a better way to convert NNTP --> MIME Message I'm certainly open to suggestions.  I'm already dropping the newsgroup header as that seems problematic for reasons I don't understand.  Basically, I just can't figure out how to parse these headers so that they create a valid message to send.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to fix the sender info.  The issue is not (quite) your code.  Your MTA is rejecting the e-mail.  Sendmail is often configured to not allow a "from" address that appears invalid.  In this case, it's telling you that a DNS lookup fails for "nospam.nospam".

Your envelope should reflect a sender of something like news2mail@myhost.org instead of trying to use the address of the usenet article poster.

There are multiple usenet news to e-mail gateways available; you might want to look at using one of them instead of rolling your own.

Comment: it seems to reject based on every single NNTP header -- none of them, or very few, seem to translate to MIME directly.